# How to use a floreant pos project developed by others in my system?

Tags: java, pos

I know java but I am a newbie in floreant pos. I have downloaded the floreant pos and ran it's batch file. But when I want to use others project I am unable find that file in it. How can use and modify it?
[The thing I want to reuse is this project](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/floreantpos/code/trunk%20floreantpos-code)

Comment: Sorry, I VTC because this is very unclear at present - you'd need to explain exactly what the "Floreant pos" is, what "running its batch file" does, what you mean by you want to "use other project", and what you've tried so far (preferably with code samples) for us to be able to help here.

Comment: Floreant Pos is a restaurant point of sale software which  helps restaurant operations easier. We can change the menu and other items such as kitchen tables in it. I want to use others project which they have developed but I am unable to know how to use it